Signing nupkg packages on Linux
On Windows, we can use the built in nuget sign command and a certificate from the Windows certificate store. The beauty of it is we can have any KSP to perform the actual signing. The private key does not need to be on the build machine that runs the nuget sign command. Thus, it works with any HSM or key provider, no need for a PFX file.
On Linux, there is no central key store for X.509 certificates. The most common way of signing is GPG which is unfortunately self-signed, and you have to distribute the signature as a detached file. This creates a problem for nuget Artifactory, because the nuget repository does not allow loose files. Is there a better way of signing on Linux? Preferably some utility that works with an X.509 certificate and can generate the same signature format as the nuget sign command on Windows?
